# Set a default value to an AdvancedDataGridColumn

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid, dataprovider

I am using the following code, to create an AdvancedDataGridColumn, to be added to an AdvancedDataGrid:

```
var columnValue:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
columnValue.headerText="Value";
columnValue.dataField="value";          
columnValue.itemRenderer=new ClassFactory(valueRenderer);
columnValue.rendererIsEditor = true;
columnValue.editable = true;
```

I would like to supply the AdvancedDataGrid with a dataProvider that contains a range of objects, some of which DON'T have the "value" field. When such an object is encountered, the grid should not display any text for it in the "value" column (It will have info in another column, and I don't need its "value" data).

How can this be done?

Comment: You can code that directly in the renderer; or you can use a labelfunction.

Comment: @Reboog711 Can you direct me to an example?

Comment: I don't have time to put together a sample.  Documentation is pretty good on both creating renderers and using a labelFunction.  It looks like you're already using a custom itemRenderer, so I would modify / extend that. Conceptually, in a `dataChange()` event handler have a conditional that introspects the data object somehow and sets the display value based on the data.